# Doble click en componentes UL LI Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7

Quisiera saber como evitar que el mis ul li se hagan doble click solo.
Por ejemplo

```
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="text-light" href="#">Categorias</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li (click)="irArticulos(dep.Codigo,'dep')" *ngFor="let dep of arrDepartamentos"><a >{{dep.Descripcion}}</a>

            <ul class="third-level-menu">
              <li (click)="irArticulos(fam.Codigo,'fam')" *ngFor="let fam of dep.ListFamilias"><a >{{fam.Descripcion}}</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>



        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Este es el codigo de mis ul's y cuando hago click en el de abajo en el de third-level-menu, es como que se hace click tambien en el li de second-level-menu y me redirecciona al primero no al segundo que es donde hago click

Comment: cambia los click a los anchor tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los eventos en angular están disponibles también usando la variable [`$event`](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object). No deberías [abusar de su uso](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice) pero puedes suspender la propagación del evento de esa forma.

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
  <li>
    <a class="text-light" href="#">Categorias</a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li (click)="irArticulos($event, dep.Codigo,'dep')" *ngFor="let dep of arrDepartamentos"><a >{{dep.Descripcion}}</a>
        <ul class="third-level-menu">
          <li (click)="irArticulos($event, fam.Codigo,'fam')" *ngFor="let fam of dep.ListFamilias"><a >{{fam.Descripcion}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Luego agregas un parámetro al componente llamado `$event`. Puedes cambiarle luego la posición, yo lo puse como el primero para ponerte un ejemplo. Lo importante es que coincida con la posición del `$event` en tu html. Improvisé los nombres de los parámetros pues no tengo el código de tu componente.

```
irArticulos($event: any, codigo: string, otro: string) {
   $event.stopPropagation(); // Para que no se propague a los componentes inferiores
   // El resto de tu código
}
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias! me sirvió el consejo!

Comment: @JorgeFabris No te olvides votar y/o marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Comment: Buena respuesta.